# Websocket on Azure with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, azure, express, websocket

I manage to make websocket work on a nodeJS+express application on azure.
However it is using polling instead of websocket, anyone know why is that?
Here are the config.

#### Client Side

`socket  = io.connect(url, {'transports':['websocket', 'polling']);`

#### Server side

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.info('Express server started');
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});
```

I am using socket.io 1.3.6

#### EDIT:

On Azure I have websocket and the Always On setting ON. 
It's also not a the free package.

Comment: What do you mean by azure? VM, cloud service or azure website?

Comment: @LuisDelgado it is azure website

Comment: How are you deploying?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I also have a socketIO app hosted on an azure website, and the web sockets does work as expected. Did you check this article out? [Enabling Websockets for Socket.io Node apps on Microsoft Azure](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingWebsocketsForSocketioNodeAppsOnMicrosoftAzure.aspx)

Here's the important part:

> Note that we say "webSocket enabled=false" in this web.config. This is
>   confusing, but makes sense when you realize we're saying "disable
>   Websockets in IIS and let node (or whomever) downstream handle it"

Comment: yes I did follow through that article. Yet websocket still works with polling. I have now set the client setting to `socket  = io.connect(url);`

Comment: @fredtma Can you confirm that your edited web.config is getting uploaded to your website instance? It has happened to me in the past that it was not, and I confirmed that by using Kudu.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downgrading socket.io to 1.3.5 to get websockets to work on Azure (iisnode)